# gluLookAt() has no effect in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-compat

I'm trying to look at the square from the other side using the gluLookAt() function.
After using the function, nothing changes, although I expected that the corners of the square will change.
I set the camera point to the rightmost part of the world and look at its center, where the square is located.
He had to stretch out to the sides. Why hasn't anything changed?

Code:

```
#include "includes.h"

using namespace std;

constexpr auto FPS_RATE = 60;
int windowHeight = 600, windowWidth = 600, windowDepth = 600;

void init();
void idleFunction();
void displayFunction();
double getTime();

double getTime()
{
    using Duration = std::chrono::duration<double>;
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<Duration>(
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
        ).count();
}

const double frame_delay = 1.0 / FPS_RATE;
double last_render = 0;

void init()
{
    glutDisplayFunc(displayFunction);
    glutIdleFunc(idleFunction);
    glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-windowWidth / 2, windowWidth / 2, -windowHeight / 2, windowHeight / 2, -windowDepth / 2, windowDepth / 2);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
}

void idleFunction()
{
    const double current_time = getTime();
    if ((current_time - last_render) > frame_delay)
    {
        last_render = current_time;
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}

void displayFunction()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    gluLookAt(-300, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0);
    glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
    glVertex3i(-150, 150, 0);
    glVertex3i(150, 150, 0);
    glVertex3i(150, -150, 0);
    glVertex3i(-150, -150, 0);
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    glutInitWindowPosition((GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - windowWidth) / 2, (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - windowHeight) / 2);
    glutCreateWindow("Window");
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is caused because [`gluLookAt()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) is call with in a `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequence. This is not allowed. You've to call `gluLookAt` before `glBegin`.
Once drawing of primitives was started by [`glBegin`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) it is only allowed to specify vertex coordinates ([`glVertex`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glGetError.xml)) and change attributes (e.g. [`glColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml), [`glTexCoord`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexCoord.xml) ...), till the drawn is ended (`glEnd`).
All other instruction will be ignored and cause a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error (error code 1282).

Further note, that `glLookAt` doesn't set a the current matrix. It defines a matrix and multiplies the current matrix by the new matrix. Set the matrix mode ([`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml)) and set [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) by [`glLoadIdentity`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadIdentity.xml) before `gluLookAt`.

With the view matrix

> ```cpp
> gluLookAt(-300, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
> ```

you want "see" anything, because with that matrix the line of sight is set along the x-axis and you look at the 2 dimensional polygon from the side.

Note, the polygon is a 2D object. The size of the object appears different if you look at it from the front, from the side (then it is a line and not visible) or from an direction in between. The first 3 parameters of `gluLookAt` define the point of view the next 3 parameters define the point you look at. The vector from the point of view to the point you look at is the line of sight.

Probably yo want look along the z-axis:

```cpp
void displayFunction()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0, 0, -300, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);    

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
    glVertex3i(-150, 150, 0);
    glVertex3i(150, 150, 0);
    glVertex3i(150, -150, 0);
    glVertex3i(-150, -150, 0);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

You use [Orthographic (parallel) projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Orthographic_projection). If you would use [Perspective projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection), then the projected size of the object would decrease, when the distance to the point of view increases. Perspective projection can be set by [`gluPerspective`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml). e.g.:

```cpp
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(90.0, (double)windowWidth / windowHeight, 0.1, 600.0);
```

Comment: I tried your option, but I only see a black screen.

Comment: @ Yes I extended the answer. You've to `gluLookAt(0, 0, -300, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);`

Comment: I added `glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); glLoadIdentity(); gluPerspective(90.0, (double)window Width / window Height, 0.1, 600.0);` to my `init();` function. In `displayFunction();` I added `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); glLoadIdentity(); gluLookAt(0, 0, -300, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);` after `glClear(...)` and before `glEnable(...)`. When running I square as a very small dot in the center.

Comment: @Герман Read the answer *"... the projected size of the object would decrease, when the distance to the point of view increases..."*. Use `gluLookAt(0, 0, -50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);` and the object will increase.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But still, it seems to me that the program behaves incorrectly. When you move the camera at least a pixel to the side, the square stretches too much. I posted a video on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/gYrZsb2UF6c) with this problem. I would be happy if you would look at it and explain to me why this is happening. Thanks.